# mod_ssl vs mod24_ssl AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, mod-ssl

Going through the motions to get TLS up and running for my website. I read under the AWS documentation to

`sudo yum install -y mod24_ssl`

but was getting a conflict on some dependencies.

I ended up reading a blog where someone mentioned `sudo yum install mod_ssl` and I ended up running that without any issues. Can someone let me know if this safe? What's the difference between mod_ssl and mod24_ssl?

Thanks

Comment: mod_ssl would be for Apache 2.2.x and mod24_ssl would be for Apache 2.4.x.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @stdunbar said `mod_ssl` works with Apache 2.2 and `mod24_ssl` works with Apache 2.4.

We can see that the package descriptions are similar except for the Version:

```
[ec2-user]$ yum info mod_ssl
Available Packages
Name        : mod_ssl
Arch        : x86_64
Epoch       : 1
Version     : 2.2.32
Release     : 1.9.amzn1
Size        : 107 k
Repo        : amzn-updates/latest
Summary     : SSL/TLS module for the Apache HTTP Server
URL         : http://httpd.apache.org/
License     : ASL 2.0
Description : The mod_ssl module provides strong cryptography for the Apache Web
            : server via the Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) and Transport Layer
            : Security (TLS) protocols.

[ec2-user]$ yum info mod24_ssl
Installed Packages
Name        : mod24_ssl
Arch        : x86_64
Epoch       : 1
Version     : 2.4.27
Release     : 3.71.amzn1
Size        : 224 k
Repo        : installed
From repo   : amzn-updates
Summary     : SSL/TLS module for the Apache HTTP Server
URL         : http://httpd.apache.org/
License     : ASL 2.0
Description : The mod_ssl module provides strong cryptography for the Apache Web
            : server via the Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) and Transport Layer
            : Security (TLS) protocols.
```

We can see what each package depends on using `yum deplist`:

```
[ec2-user]$ yum deplist mod_ssl
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
26 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
package: mod_ssl.x86_64 1:2.2.32-1.9.amzn1
  ... snip ...
  dependency: httpd = 2.2.32-1.9.amzn1
   provider: httpd.x86_64 2.2.32-1.9.amzn1
  ... snip ...

[ec2-user]$ yum deplist mod24_ssl
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
26 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
package: mod24_ssl.x86_64 1:2.4.27-3.71.amzn1
  ... snip ...
  dependency: httpd24 = 2.4.27-3.71.amzn1
   provider: httpd24.x86_64 2.4.27-3.71.amzn1
  ... snip ...
```

`httpd` and `httpd24` conflict--you can't have both installed at the same time.

Answer (score 8):

If your AWS instance is using the Amazon Linux 2 AMI you will use mod_ssl for Apache 2.4 installs.

Note the mod_ssl version is "2.4.6" and the AWS Repository is "amzn2-core".

```
Available Packages
Name        : mod_ssl
Arch        : x86_64
Epoch       : 1
Version     : 2.4.6
Release     : 67.amzn2.6.1
Size        : 110 k
Repo        : amzn2-core/2017.12/x86_64
Summary     : SSL/TLS module for the Apache HTTP Server
URL         : http://httpd.apache.org/
License     : ASL 2.0
Description : The mod_ssl module provides strong cryptography for the Apache Web
            : server via the Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) and Transport Layer
            : Security (TLS) protocols.
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Everything I saw said mod24_ssl but there wasn't one for Amazon Linux 2, and sure enough, mod_ssl installs as 2.4.46-1.amzn2 for me from @amzn2-core.